# Does Robotium support OpenGL?

Tags: android, testing, opengl-es, robotium

I want to create android automation tool for my own app with the help of either Robotium or NativeDriver. I have used OpenGL GLSurfaceView for 3D objects in my android app. Could anyone tell me which of the above (Robotium/NativeDriver) supports OpenGL?

Answer (score 1):

Well i will start of by saying, dont use NativeDriver, support was dropped a long time ago for it.

On to the next point, robotium will support you getting hold of the surfaceview but will only be able to tell you about the internal state of the object as much as you have methods allowing you to, it has no built in support for finding out what is happening within opengl.

Depending on what you are trying to test, that may or may not be enough though.

Answer (score 1):

Robotium does support automating user actions on OpenGL app using 'touch-based-on-position' actions through method:
`solo.ClickOnScreen(float x, float y);`

However, you CAN NOT capture the evidence with `solo.takeScreenshot` method because you will end up getting blank(black) jpg files without any of your app content in it.

I just hit the wall with the same problem, not able to capture the screenshot.